# CSS Transition in which a zoomed image overlaps the whole image gallery

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

I am attempting to perform a CSS3 transition and overlay on a picture gallery and would like a little help determining how to control the effect properly. It would seem I need to divide the 8 images into 4 slightly different div wrappers depending on the position (top left corner image needs to grow by 200% to the right and down, the top right corner image needs to grow by 200% to the left and down, etc., etc.). My intent is to eliminate clipping off the screen or with another container/element.

Each image should grown and cover the adjacent 3 images such that no clipping occurs with other elements in other sections or clip off the extent of the window. This should happen for both the image and the text overlay (the text overlay is temporarily disabled).

Could I please have a few suggestions on how to perform this type of effect?

The following is just a very simple sample of what I am attempting to do. (I don't seem to understand how to maintain row position during the transition either.)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
    .div-table{
      display:table;
      width: auto;
    }
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      -webkit-transition-property: width, height; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0*/
      -webkit-transition-duration: 4s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
      transition-property: width, height;
      transition-duration: 4s;
    }
    div:hover {
      position:absolute;
      z-index: 10;
      width: 425px;
      height: 425px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <h1>My Gallery of Color Boxes</h1>

  <p>Hover over the element below, and it will expand to cover the other 
     elements in the table</p>
  <div class="div-table">
        <div style="background:red; "></div>
        <div style="background:green;"></div>
        <div style="background:purple;"></div>
        <div style="background:blue;"></div>
  </div>    
  <div class="div-table">
        <div style="background:black;"></div>
        <div style="background:yellow;"></div>
        <div style="background:brown;"></div>
        <div style="background:orange;"></div>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tried playing with a `scale()` transformation

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZrmvYx)

---

The base placement of the blocks is done via Flexbox. When you hover a `div` the property `transform: scale(4, 2)` will stretch the block by `4` times its width and by `2` times its height. As a result the whole outer element will be covered.

If you need to stretch more in height change the 2<sup>nd</sup> value of `scale()`. All other blocks not hovered will stand in their position.

Of course for each block you need to set the right `transform-origin` property.

---

**Markup**

```
<div class="div-table">
    <div style="background:red; "></div>
    <div style="background:green;"></div>
    <div style="background:purple;"></div>
    <div style="background:blue;"></div>
    <div style="background:black;"></div>
    <div style="background:yellow;"></div>
    <div style="background:brown;"></div>
    <div style="background:orange;"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.div-table {
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 400px;
}

.div-table div {
    flex: 0 0 100px;
    height: 100px;
    transition: 1s transform;
}

.div-table div:hover {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: scale(4, 2);
}


.div-table div:nth-child(1) { transform-origin : 0 0; }
.div-table div:nth-child(2) { transform-origin : 33.3% 0; }
.div-table div:nth-child(3) { transform-origin : 66.6% 0; }
.div-table div:nth-child(4) { transform-origin : 100% 0; }
.div-table div:nth-child(5) { transform-origin : 0     100%; }
.div-table div:nth-child(6) { transform-origin : 33.3% 100%; }
.div-table div:nth-child(7) { transform-origin : 66.6% 100%; }
.div-table div:nth-child(8) { transform-origin : 100%  100%; }
```

Calculating all those `transform-origin` by hand can be tedious, so for your convenience you could generate them by `SASS` with a couple of nested for-loop based on the amount of rows and columns, like I've done in this [SassMeister snippet](https://www.sassmeister.com/gist/c66ae67b79c8efe960753cba5c82de91)

```
/* =============== */
$rows    : 2;
$columns : 4;
/* =============== */

$imagecounter : 1;    
@for $i from 1 through $rows {
  @for $j from 1 through $columns {
    div:nth-child(#{$imagecounter}) {
      transform-origin: 
        100%/($columns - 1) * ($j - 1)
        100%/($rows - 1) * ($i - 1);
    }
    $imagecounter : $imagecounter + 1;
  }
}
```

---

Here is another example of an actual image gallery with squared images

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Zrmvyj)

In this demo I've changed the transform to `scale(4, 4)` (so as to keep the `1:1` aspect ratio) and some of the y-coordinates of the `transform-origin`

The inner images have a simple style applied

```
.div-table img { 
    width: 100%; 
}
```

so they can seamlessly scale during the transition of their parent div.

---

**Final Result**

[image]

Finally, for a matter of *usability* I'd like to suggest the insertion of a small margin amongst the inner `div`, so the make easier the selection of the images in the center of the grid, especially if you plan to have more than 2 rows of images.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance!

Comment: @airsoftsoldrecn9 you're welcome.If this answer solved you may consider to mark it as the accepted.